# Como verificar se servidor está disponivel antes do request.urlopen em Python?

Tags: python, json, http, http-request, urllib

Tenho o seguinte código para requisição HTTP no meu servidor no meu código python:

```
import urllib.request
import json

url= urllib.request.urlopen('http://ENDERECOIP/pasta/arquivo.php')
x= url.read()
y = json.loads(x.decode('utf-8'))
teste = y['valor']
print(teste)
```

O código funciona e retorna o valor mas queria fazer uma verificação anteriormente para caso o servidor não esteja disponível ele retorne uma mensagem "Servidor indisponível".

Comment: Se o servidor está disponível, qual seria a resposta da sua requisição?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente usar um `try` e `except`, assim:

```
import urllib.request
import json

try:
    url= urllib.request.urlopen('http://ENDERECOIP/pasta/arquivo.php')
    x= url.read()
    y = json.loads(x.decode('utf-8'))
    teste = y['valor']
    print(teste)

except Exception as e:
    print("Servidor indisponível. Erro:", e)
```

O `urlopen` só consegue completar a requisição com o servidor ativo.

Comment: Quase isso. Se a resposta não for um JSON válido a mensagem "Servidor indisponível" irá aparecer mesmo estando disponível.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente para o que eu precisava! Muito obrigada!

Answer (score 0):

A forma mais fácil e simples de se fazer isso é utilizando a biblioteca [`requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/). Utilize a função `requests.get` passando a url que deseja verificar. Essa função retornará um objeto de `Response` que contém o atributo `status_code`. Para saber se está tudo certo, basta verificar o código retornado na resposta. Exemplo:

```
import requests
url = "https://www.youtube.com"

if requests.get(url).status_code == 200:
    print("O servidor está disponível.")
else:
    print("O servidor está indisponível.")
```

Obviamente existem muitas outras formas de verificar se um servidor está disponível ou não, mas na minha opinião, está forma é a mais simples.

Comment: `status_code == 200` não é a única resposta de servidor disponível. Com a sua ideia, a opção mais adequada seria `status_code // 100 == 2`. Mas isso também não garantiria um funcionamento totalmente correto, pois nem todas as respostas diferentes de 2xx indicam um servidor indisponível: 4xx indica um "client error" e 1xx indica "informação", por exemplo.

Com as informações do OP eu consideraria servidor indisponível apenas as respostas 5xx. 

Uma opção mais ampla é testar a resposta com a função `raise_for_status()`.

Comment: Eu sei que o código 200 não é o único para servidores disponíveis, mas isso só foi um exemplo. Ele pode fazer uma lista cheia de códigos e verificar se o código da resposta do servidor está dentro dela.